# Custom Form Data Submitting to Sharepoint List using Javascript 403 error

Tags: sharepoint

I am struggling in submitting values from a custom form once submitted to a SP list, it is display a 403 error but it is my sharepoint list and I have full admin rights, I have cleared cache and done all the recommended stuff online, anyone know where, i have commented it all out but the first row just to stepping over them all when placing the break point

Here is my code, thanks in advance:

```html
function uploadToList() {

   var map = {};
   // $(".form-control").each(function () {
   //  map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
   // });

   console.log(map);
   var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
   var clientContext =  SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List');
   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
   this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

   oListItem.set_item('Title', "Hello World");
   // oListItem.set_item('_FX0078_Fcy4', map.issuename);
   // oListItem.set_item('rywe', map.status);
   // oListItem.set_item('ttey', map.assigned);
   // oListItem.set_item('w3ubg', map.journeyclass);
   // oListItem.set_item('_FX006d_F281', map.product);
   // oListItem.set_item('tdrl', map.source);
   // oListItem.set_item('h0ds', map.dateraised);
   // oListItem.set_item('yl0n', map.description);
   // oListItem.set_item('_x0073_hd3', map.recordsanalysed);
   // oListItem.set_item('_0064_zr2', map.discrepant);
   // oListItem.set_item('nmfk', map.completed);
   // oListItem.set_item('wjxk', map.analysispending);
   // oListItem.set_item('dyma', map.datepending);
   // oListItem.set_item('mija', map.percent);
   // oListItem.set_item('sj6s', map.groupingcompleted);
   // oListItem.set_item('_Fx006b_Fqm6', map.clensecompleted);
   // oListItem.set_item('xdgr', map.InitialETA);
   // oListItem.set_item('r9mz', map.actualETA);
   // oListItem.set_item('rywe', map.status);
   // oListItem.set_item('SR_Fx0020_FNo_Fx002e_F', map.srnumber);
   // oListItem.set_item('rf0v', map.rca);
   // oListItem.set_item('beaf', map.priorty);
   // oListItem.set_item('xcah', map.benefits);
   // oListItem.set_item('Attachment', map.myfile);

   oListItem.update();
   clientContext.load(oListItem);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }

  function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   alert("Success")
  }

  function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
   alert("Failed" + args.get_message())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The script seems fine, if you run the script in a SharePoint page(Script editor webpart/content editor webpart).

Make sure the user who execute the script has enough permission to list(if could create item form UI).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="getPollval">Submit</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("getPollval").onclick = function () {
            createListItem("Test");
        }
        //var siteUrl = '/';
        function createListItem(pollValue, pId, pollTitle) {

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();//SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');

            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

            oListItem.set_item('Title', pollValue);
            //oListItem.set_item('Response', pollValue);
            //oListItem.set_item('PollID', pId);

            oListItem.update();

            clientContext.load(oListItem);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded() {

            alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you, I didn't realise that you have to place .aspx .html or any file in the Content Web editor for Authentication so i was just loading the file in the URL which was problem number one. Just done it and its successfully added an item to a list.